# Unable to Publish Angular Application After Microsoft Build Engine Upgrade

Tags: azure-devops, node-sass

Some time last week Microsoft DevOps upgraded the Build Engine from:

Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.2.32702+c4012a063 for .NET Core

TO

Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.3.0+0f4c62fea for .NET Core

It seems that this has update NODE to version 13 and has caused an Npm package (node-saas) installation to stop working...

```
> node-sass@4.9.3 install D:\a\1\s\Website\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.9.3/win32-x64-72_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.9.3/win32-x64-72_binding.node": 

HTTP error 404 Not Found
```

Before the upgrade:

```
 > node-sass@4.9.3 install D:\a\1\s\Website\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\node-sass
 > node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.9.3/win32-x64-64_binding.node
Download complete
```

It seems like the URL changes from:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.9.3/win32-x64-64_binding.node

TO

https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.9.3/win32-x64-72_binding.node

Can someone please help fix this issue? Perhaps I can specify the engine version in Azure DevOps...

[image]

Comment: That's great you fix this by updating to angular 8. You can post your solution and accept it,  so that others whose encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 2):

We were able to resolve this issue in our build system by adding the `Use Node.js ecosystem` task in our pipeline prior to the `npm install` task.

- Check the node environment in your development machine where it works, make a note.
- Add a new task to your pipeline and search for the "Node.js tool installer".
- Specify the node version that you want to use in this task
- Save the pipeline

The pipeline yaml looks something like the following:

```
steps:
- task: UseNode@1
  displayName: 'Use Node 8.12.0'
  inputs:
    version: 8.12.0
```

<s>We also switched from using `npm install` to `npm ci` at the same time, but I don't believe it to be related at this moment.</s> Update: We tried using only `npm ci` and this did not solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I ended by upgrading to Angular 8 as well as all dependencies and the issue got fixes

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing the node_modules folder and package-lock.json, and clear the cache, then run `npm install` on your local machine.

```
   #remove node_module folder
   #remove package-lock.json

    npm cache clean
    npm install
```

This will update node-sass to its latest version. And then push the changes to your git repo and rerun your pipeline. Check [here](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#npm) for more information.

win32-x64-72_binding.node is not available for node sass 4.9.3. so it should be able to fix this issue when node sass update to the latest v4.13.0, check [here](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases) for more information.

Addition:

To execute above command in your pipeline. You can add tasks as below example to execute above command. and run npm install. You need to config the setting according to your project for these tasks
[image]

Comment: Its now working locally, however I'm still having issues in the Azure Pipeline after committing the package-lock.json file... Any ideas?

Comment: You can also add run remove command and npm install command in your pipeline.